# Sendmail by using Joomla! settings is very slow

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-mail

In my Joomla! 4.2+ component, i have something with send mail when an user submit a from, the issue is that the sending mail process is very slow. My component fetch the mail settings from the Joomla! configuration panel. This is the code, i don't see what this code hang the process of controller when submit the form :

```
abstract class MycomponentEmail
{
public static function send($mail, array $receivers)
{
    if (isset(static::$mailer_error_status)) {
        // Mailer is broken, so prevent any sending
        Log::add(static::$mailer_error_status->getMessage(), Log::ERROR, 'mycomponent');

        return false;
    } 
   
    $chunks = array_chunk($receivers, $emailRecipientCount);

    $success = true;

    foreach ($chunks as $emails) {
       if ($emailRecipientCount == 1 || $emailRecipientPrivacy == 'to') {
          $mail->ClearAddresses();
          $mail->addRecipient($emails);
       } elseif ($emailRecipientPrivacy == 'cc') {
          $mail->ClearCCs();
          $mail->addCC($emails);
       } else {
          $mail->ClearBCCs();
          $mail->addBCC($emails);
       }

       try {
          $mail->Send();
       } catch (Exception $e) {
          $success = false;
          Log::add($e->getMessage(), Log::ERROR, 'mycomponent');
       }
   }

   return $success;

   }
   }
```

The controller call that :

```
public function sendNotification($url = null, $approved = false)
{
    // Create email.
        $mail = Factory::getMailer();
        $mail->setSubject($mailsubject);
        $mail->setSender([$config->getEmail(), $mailnamesender]);

        // Send email to all subscribers.
        if (!empty($receivers[1])) {
            $this->attachEmailBody($mail, 1, $subject, $url, $once);
            MycomponentEmail::send($mail, $receivers[1]);
        }
}
```